# UIView mask triangle

Tags: ios, swift, cgpath

I would like to add a triangle mask pattern to the bottom and top edge of my UIView. Something like this:

[image: virtual 'Harry Potter' ticket with triangle pattern at top and bottopm]

So far I was only able to draw the bottom pattern:

[image: Red box with triangle cutout pattern at bottom]

```
let constant: CGFloat = 5
let width = rect.width
let height = rect.height

var p = CGPoint.zero
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: .zero)

p.x = width
path.addLine(to: p)
p.y = height
path.addLine(to: p)

var i = 0
var value = false
while Double(i) <= Double(width + 10) {
    value.toggle()
    if value {
        p.x -= constant
        p.y -= constant
        path.addLine(to: p)
    } else {
        p.x -= constant;
        p.y += constant;
        path.addLine(to: p)
    }
    i += 1
}
path.close()

let maskShape = CAShapeLayer()
maskShape.path = path.cgPath
layer.mask = maskShape
```

How can I create the view with the triangle pattern on the top and bottom edges?

Thank you

Comment: I don't know how to create the path for the upper triangle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have most of the logic.

Think of having a pen drawing on a sheet of paper with coordinates.

```
 /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\
|                |
|                |
|                |
 \/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/
```

So CGPoint.zero is top left and will be the start of our drawing.

```
    +    
     /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\
    |                |
    |                |
    |                |
     \/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/


var point = CGPoint.zero
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: point)
```

So, let's draw the triangles.

```
----------------->
 /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\
|                |
|                |
|                |
 \/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/


var i = 0
var value = true
while Double(i) <= Double(width + 10) {
    value.toggle()
    point.x += constant
    if value {
        point.y -= constant
    } else {
        point.y += constant;
    }
    path.addLine(to: point)
    i += 1
}
```

We are now at top right, so let's continue our drawing and let's go to bottom right:

```
 /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\
|                | |
|                | |
|                | |
 \/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ ˇ 

point = CGPoint(x: width, y: height)
path.addLine(to: point)
```

Now, we need the triangles until reaching bottom left:

```
 /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\
|                |
|                |
|                |
 \/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/
<-----------------

i = 0
value = true
while Double(i) <= Double(width + 10) {
    value.toggle()
    point.x -= constant
    if value {
        point.y += constant
    } else {
        point.y -= constant;
    }
    path.addLine(to: point)
    i += 1
}
```

Now, let's go back to starting point and close:

```
^   /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\
|  |                |
|  |                |
|  |                |
    \/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/

point = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0) //Not needed, but I find it cleaner to add it
path.addLine(to: point) //Not needed, but I find it cleaner to add it
path.close()
```

Side note, I factorize a little your loop, since you are doing repetitive command inside the if/else, I put them outside.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it's very clear!